# References in object optimisation

Tags: javascript, optimization, object, reference

We have a little argue about the best practices when using objects. Some of us use the following way to get object property value:

```
object[a][b][...][z]
```

other ones claims that if you use the following code once

```
var ref=object[a][b][...][z]
```

and then use the "ref" variable anytime when you need the specific object value is faster.

Has anyone knew if there is a optimization in the second case? For example if you need to loop trough large object:

```
//with reference
for(var a in object){

    for(var b in object[a]){

        ...

            var ref=object[a][b][...][y];

            for(var z in object[a][b][...][z]){

                if(ref){
                    ....
                }
            }
        ...
    }
}

//without reference
for(var a in object){

    for(var b in object[a]){

        ...

            for(var z in object[a][b][...][z]){

                if(object[a][b][...][y]){
                    ....
                }
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it for yourself on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com)! See http://jsperf.com/ref-or-no-ref for your particular case. The 'ref' version is 10% faster than the 'no-ref' version (Win7, Chrome). That makes sense, since the 'ref' version saves you a few object lookups (the 'ref' points directly to the end), but then again I don't know what inline caching exactly does and how much it optimises object lookups. I would be interested to see an elaboration on how much object lookups actually cost these days...!

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Fair enough, I will try it, but I am hopping for some explanation in the JavaScript specifications ..

Comment: Was still running the test :) See updated answer

Comment: @Joro: I would also like to know the internal's answer. It probably involves inline caching and more things to make object lookups fast. But I just don't know enough about it to deduce a theoretical answer. Hence the practical variant.

Comment: You are right. It is faster to use references. How much faster depends on your browser, OS and of course your JavaScript, but it is the better way. The only thing left is someone to explain why :-]

Comment: Well, it saves object lookups, so that makes sense (added that to the answer for later readers). I'm particularly interested in *how much* it saves you! And what inline caching means in this all... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'ref' version saves you object lookups, so it should be faster.

A jsperf test confirms this: http://jsperf.com/ref-or-no-ref